# Blender keeps rendering same image even after switching off sequencer

Tags: rendering, image-sequence

Blender rendering is stuck on old scene. I've tried turning off the sequencer as that's what people have suggested online but it keeps showing the same image over and over. Anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: screenshot? Do you mean you are seing an image in the image viewer? Do you have a 3d view open at all? Maybe you need to switch to a 3d viewporr?

Comment: What does 'showing the image' mean? is this in a render result? How did you turn off the sequencer? Is there a clip still loaded in it? etc. Please give us some details to help us out, here, or the question is liable to be closed as unclear.